# Autofill data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I have an Excel sheet with 8 columns and 1500 rows.

There are two label data columns in which(limit) From(Start) and To(End) is mentioned. My requirement is to fill the rows based on the limit.

Example: In first row there is 1(from) to 100(to). Then I want to fill 1 to 100 in rows(100) and drag the remaining columns data in that to all the 100 rows. Only label data column is changing in each row and remaining data is common. I want to do this for 100 rows.

I tried to fill each row by manual dragging. Is there any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear how 6 columns get populated to 100 columns

Comment: @TimWilliams As remaining columns data is fixed and same data has to be filled to all 100 rows( not 100 Columns)

Comment: @Asger edited and attached two images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Data and Output]

You can try the code below:

```
Sub autoFillDataInExcel()

Dim dSh As Worksheet
Set dSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA") 'Worksheet that contains data to process
Dim oSH As Worksheet
Set oSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT") 'Ouput data

Dim data1 As String, data2 As String
Dim rFrom As Long, rTo As Long
Dim ouputRow As Long
outputRow = 2 'Default row for output worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For a = 2 To dSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Loop until the last row of Column A
    'Transfer data to variable
    data1 = dSh.Range("A" & a).Value
    data2 = dSh.Range("B" & a).Value
    rFrom = dSh.Range("C" & a).Value
    rTo = dSh.Range("D" & a).Value

    For b = rFrom To rTo 'Loop based on the range number
        oSH.Range("A" & outputRow).Value = data1
        oSH.Range("B" & outputRow).Value = data2
        oSH.Range("C" & outputRow).Value = b
        outputRow = outputRow + 1 'Increment Output row for the next data
    Next b
Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```